# Unirationality and the Hasse principle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Is there an example of a quasiprojective variety $X$ defined over ℚ such that

1. $X$ is unirational over all finite fields, and
2. $X$ is unirational over $\mathbb{R}$, and
3. $X$ is **not** unirational over $\mathbb{Q}$, and
4. $X(\mathbb{Q})\neq \emptyset$.

It would be easy to produce trivial examples if we do not demand (3), for example smooth cubic surfaces which violate the Hasse principle.

Comment: I think you also want to assume $X$ is not unirational?

Comment: Yes I am sorry, in fact that was the point of my question (edited).

Comment: You can take the (quite singular) projective cone over a smooth cubic surface violating the Hasse principle.  The only rational point will be the vertex of the cone.

Comment: That is a good example, could you please explain a bit why there would be no other $\mathbb{Q}$ points ? Thanks!